# Changing memory allocation policy on Linux

Tags: linux, threads, memory

How can I change memory allocation policy on Linux?

On Solaris it's done system-wide with **lgrp_mem_default_policy** ([man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1450/ggkom.html#ggkmd)) and  **pmadvise** ([man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/pmadvise-1.html#scrolltoc)) is a per process equivalent that does not require root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses different memory management subsystems than Solaris, of course, so not every tuneable has an equivalent. Looks like the `numactl` utility is the closest analogue for this particular setting. Look at `man 8 numactl` and `man 2 set_mempolicy`.

Comment: +1 Look right. Let me check it out...

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: I would add `apt-get install numactl` and `apt-get install libnuma-dev` (for man pages) to the answer.

Comment: Unless you're on Red Hat / Fedora, in which case that won't work. You didn't specify. :) (In fact, on those distributions, the numactl utility, with its man pages, are in the Base group and so installed by default on every system.)